# How to ignore all css written outside of specific component of a large project?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am having trouble localizing css within a very large project. Essentially, I had 2 products, to which I added a third product. However, for my third product, I used tailwind.

Now, I am having trouble only using the tailwind css and ignoring the rest of the css written across the app. How can I ignore the bootstrap and other css written across the app?

I've tried css resets, and I've also directly inputted the tailwind output but nothing has worked. Any advice/help would be awesome, thank you! (screenshots attached)

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSenE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

delete bootstrap.min.css then clear your page's browser cache and u'll be all set

Comment: Hi Omar, 

However I am using the bootstrap in other places in the app? As well, there are other css files being applied here (that I have made) that I am also trying to avoid using!

Comment: well basically if you want to remove bootstrap u need to change ur classnames into tailwind's since from my understanding you are trying to build your project using tailwind only and some custom css as for the other css files if you are trying to avoid them you should just change the classnames do a redesign and then remove them hope this helps u

Comment: hey, this won't work... way too much css -- pls send another solution if you know one!

Comment: hmm i guess this might be risky but you can like write a script to detect all the classnames related to the files you want to delete and then make it replace them in the html classname with "" i guess that will remove the css that u don't want and save you lots of time for example you have .header the script will find the .paragraph remove the . then search in the html files for paragraph then make it an empty string and leave the rest of the classnames beside it the way they were hope you understand what i'm saying